# Source code highlight only NSLog lines

Tags: xcode, source-highlighting

Is there a way to assign a color to `NSLog` statements so that it is easier to find them in the file.
Not in the console, the file. Here's a screenshot to clarify what I'm asking

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffnGE.png]

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to change the colour of `Other function and method names`

This will also change some other things though.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to just change NSLog statements so that I can find them easier when debugging.

Comment: NSLog is just a function that happens to print stuff. I don't think you can specify a color per function

Comment: That answer is in your screenshot. Look to the right top side. Tjere is a unselected tab that controlls font and color of the console.

Comment: Patrick. It appears that you're right. There seems to be no way to specify a color per function.

Comment: Helge, I'm not talking about the debugger console. I'm talking about the NSLog statements on the file as illustrated on the screenshot.

Answer (score -2):

Yes for syntax highlighting in xcode. You find the coloring options in xcode next to the tab source code. However the options are limited.

NSLog itself produces only pure tetx. That means no for the actual log.

But you cold parse tags along that contain colorcodes. You would then need to write a parser that ready those color codes. Bit that would mean exporting the log into a tool das trqnslate the color tags and display the text with colors. Same with html.

But for development its more handy to stick with the regular output.

Comment: From your other replies I realized that I missunderstand you. So this isnt helping the way you eant. However here is the requested link. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode